# Active Directory for linux servers

Tags: active-directory, samba, openldap, kerberos, samba4

I have 7 ubuntu servers and a Storage server on freebsd. I am considering deploying OpenLDAP on one of these 7 servers so that these servers can have a centralized user database and authentication mechanism similar to Active Directory, but I am not sure how to do it.

I assume I will deploy OpenLDAP on one server and configure the same server with samba (with the AD controller configuration). Then join the other 6 linux servers to this domain.

Will the users created on the OpenLDAP/Samba server be able to login on the other 6 servers? If yes, how is root access granted to users?

I want to share the directories on the storage server with the users so that whenever they login to a server they can simply mount it and start accessing it regardless of which  server among these 6 server they have logged in on.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am assuming is that I will deploy the OpenLDAP on one server and configure the same server with samba (with the AD controller configuration)

That won't work (and is not necessary). AD's LDAP implementation (the schema, the backend logic, etc) is vastly different from what OpenLDAP can do, so you will have to use Samba's *built-in* LDAP server instead.

Just go straight to the Samba AD deployment steps and it will automatically include LDAP service.

(That being said, there *have been* attempts to make this combination happen, through a ton of slapd overlay modules, but it's nowhere near production-ready state.)

If you don't need Windows clients, then you could use FreeIPA or plain OpenLDAP as alternative. You could even deploy local accounts via Salt/Ansible and set up just Kerberos for shared authentication (which is the core of AD's auth features anyway).

> Would the users created on the OpenLDAP/Samba server be able to login on rest of the 6 servers ?

Yes – that's the whole point of domain join, isn't it?

However, users created directly on the server (traditional useradd) will not automatically appear in AD. You must create AD accounts specifically in Samba, e.g. using `samba-tool` (or via LDAP, or using Windows RSAT GUI).

> if yes, how the root access can be given to this user?

The same way as usual: add them to sudoers.

(I believe SSSD has a mechanism to automatically translate Windows GPOs to sudoers entries, but I haven't tried that.)